# Nuxtjs Deployment on a server

Tags: apache, server, vuejs2, drupal-8, nuxt.js

i have worked on a project and i want to deploy it on my server.i used Nuxtjs(Vuejs) as a Front-end and Drupal 8 as Back-end(Headless CMS).
The issue is i uploaded the cms files on the server, now the CMS files is on

```
DOMAIN.COM/cms
```

and uploaded the Nuxtjs files on the root

```
DOMAIN.COM
```

the project is working fine on

```
DOMAIN.COM:2000/
```

and the CMS is working fine, how can i make it work on

```
DOMAIN.COM/
```

i tried alot with ProxyPass but i got the Nuxtjs working but the CMS is not.
can you please help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the question is not clear

```
CMS files is on

DOMAIN.COM/cms
and uploaded the Nuxtjs files on the root

DOMAIN.COM/cms
```

are in the same folder???...

why don't you just place your drupal server in a subdomain, like api.misite.com and your nuxt application in the main domain misite.com and make requests to the api subdomain.

almost always using subdomains instead of folders can free you from headaches with colliding apache configurations, you just have to determine if your hosting allows you subdomains (probably yes)...hope this help you

Comment: sorry about that, i edited the question, the nuxtjs files are on DOMAIN.COM, and i was thinking of adding the cms on a subdomain as you suggested